# Getting height of iframe

Tags: iframe

I need to get the height of the frame from another site, but since the information can not be obtained because of security policy can't solve this problem. Is it possible to bypass the restrictions and get the height of the site in any way, or how you can stretch the frame with a link to another domain, by full height without scroll?

Answer (score 0):

if that iframe have inline style , you can try to get that page content and get style using regular expression.